# Insert variables in a "TarFile Object" in Python

Tags: python, variables, object, tar

I want to insert some variables  in a "TarFile Object". What is the correct way? Thanks.

```
import tarfile
import datetime
import time

today = datetime.date.today()
timetoday = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print today, timetoday
print timetoday

dirname="notes"
dirnamefullpath='/var/log/something'


print today, timetoday, 'Creating archive:', dirname

tar = tarfile.open("/backups/files/sitebackup-pythontest-[today]-[timetoday]-[dirname].tar.gz", "w:gz")
for name in [dirnamefullpath]:
    tar.add(name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
for name in [dirnamefullpath]:
```

… makes a list with one element, `dirnamefullpath`, then loops over that one element.

If you want the actual files in the directory on your filesystem whose name is `dirnamefullpath`, you have to ask the computer for those filenames, usually either using [`listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) (if you just want direct children) or [`walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) (if you want all descendents, recursively).

In this case, because [`TarFile.add`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.add) knows how to recurse into directories, you probably just want the direct children. For example:

```
for name in os.listdir(dirnamefullpath):
    tar.add(name)
```